# What are the most relevant degrees that can contribute to the field of human life extension?

Tags: technology, humans, life

I would like to find a career that will greatly contribute to increase the quantity and quality of human life. What degrees, in their order of significance, might I pursue to do so?

I'm also interested in integrating technology with human biology to complete this objective. Are there specific degrees that are tailored for this field of work/study?  If so, what are they?

I realize there are facilities such as the SENS Foundation with this overall mission, but I don't think they research the benefits of incorporating technology.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is a real-life question about your own choice of study, it is outside the subject of this site. If this is about world-building for a fictional world, you're going to need to indicate that and what sort of world it's for.

Comment: Are you seriously asking for careers advice on an internet forum?

Comment: @nzaman Why not? Heeding advice unreflected would be problematic, but getting ideas and suggestions from the net is totally okay - albeit totally off-topic here.

Comment: Most of the people working at the immortality project of google are bio engineers with degrees in either biology or medicine, but new schools also offer degrees in biotechnology.

Comment: I do not believe this belongs on WorldBuilding in its current format, I would suggest rephrasing

Answer (score 0):

The extension of human life is definitely something in the biomedical field, so degrees in biomedical engineering (obviously) and perhaps biology or genetic/medical engineering for a better understanding of how humans. However, it's a lot better to consult someone better than the internet for a decision such as choosing a degree,